# Ray Worker keeps crashing

Tags: ray

I am trying to debug the issue where my Ray worker keeps crashing when running in a cluster mode.

Ray Version: 2.5.1

Starting Head node: `ray start --head --port=6379`

Starting Worker node:`ray start --address=<head-node-address:port>`

I can see both worker and head node are healthy when i start:

```
Node status
---------------------------------------------------------------
Healthy:
 1 node_23703ccdd0ed4574dba6c2806f040b8fac5f881798e658d5e4f27044
 1 node_4693b4303785ad88d5a530088d9ba6db553b4121f36b6106d7e724d6
Pending:
 (no pending nodes)
Recent failures:
 (no failures)

Resources
---------------------------------------------------------------
Usage:
 0.0/16.0 CPU
 0B/76.88GiB memory
 0B/35.51GiB object_store_memory

Demands:
 (no resource demands)
```

After few seconds, i see the worker node has crashed only showing the head node in ray status:

```
======== Autoscaler status: 2023-07-13 18:22:29.514296 ========
Node status
---------------------------------------------------------------
Healthy:
 1 node_4693b4303785ad88d5a530088d9ba6db553b4121f36b6106d7e724d6
Pending:
 (no pending nodes)
Recent failures:
 (no failures)

Resources
---------------------------------------------------------------
Usage:
 0.0/8.0 CPU
 0B/35.89GiB memory
 0B/17.94GiB object_store_memory

Demands:
 (no resource demands)
```

On checking the raylet.err,

```
[2023-07-13 18:21:33,277 C 19488 19488] (raylet) node_manager.cc:1036: [Timeout] Exiting because this node manager has mistakenly been marked as dead by the GCS: GCS failed to check the health of this node for 5 times. This is likely because the machine or raylet has become overloaded.
*** StackTrace Information ***
/data/anaconda/envs/py38_af240/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet(+0x5361ba) [0x564fec80b1ba] ray::operator<<()
/data/anaconda/envs/py38_af240/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet(+0x537ba2) [0x564fec80cba2] ray::SpdLogMessage::Flush()
/data/anaconda/envs/py38_af240/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet(+0x537eb7) [0x564fec80ceb7] ray::RayLog::~RayLog()
/data/anaconda/envs/py38_af240/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet(+0x29bb13) [0x564fec570b13] ray::raylet::NodeManager::NodeRemoved()
/data/anaconda/envs/py38_af240/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet(+0x40b0a7) [0x564fec6e00a7] ray::gcs::NodeInfoAccessor::HandleNotification()
/data/anaconda/envs/py38_af240/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet(+0x515166) [0x564fec7ea166] EventTracker::RecordExecution()
/data/anaconda/envs/py38_af240/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet(+0x4a262e) [0x564fec77762e] std::_Function_handler<>::_M_invoke()
/data/anaconda/envs/py38_af240/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet(+0x4a2b86) [0x564fec777b86] boost::asio::detail::completion_handler<>::do_complete()
/data/anaconda/envs/py38_af240/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet(+0xa97cfb) [0x564fecd6ccfb] boost::asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one()
/data/anaconda/envs/py38_af240/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet(+0xa9a289) [0x564fecd6f289] boost::asio::detail::scheduler::run()
/data/anaconda/envs/py38_af240/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet(+0xa9a742) [0x564fecd6f742] boost::asio::io_context::run()
/data/anaconda/envs/py38_af240/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet(+0x168ff2) [0x564fec43dff2] main
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xea) [0x7fdc1d9ed13a] __libc_start_main
/data/anaconda/envs/py38_af240/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet(+0x1b0567) [0x564fec485567]
```

I am trying to troubleshoot why the worker node keeps crashing shortly after stating. there is no other heavy process running on head and worker box

Any advice is much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: this was resolved. Had to open All ports between the head and the worker node. Initially i had open only 8265, 6379 and 10000- 19999 as mentioned in ray documentation.

Comment: Please turn that commen

Answer (score 2):

(In order to get this out of the list of unanswered questions, I turn the comment  by the question author into an answer post. I will be happy to remove this when the author turns their comment into their own answer post. Admittedly if I do not get showevered in praise and other positive feedback by then...)

> this was resolved. Had to open All ports between the head and the worker node. Initially i had open only 8265, 6379 and 10000- 19999 as mentioned in ray documentation.